# Search API Database Search score calculation

Tags: 8, search

I'm trying to understand how the Search API Database Search calculates the score for a search result. I understand Solr uses the [Lucene scoring model](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-search-relevancy.html) and there's also command that can be used to output the actual calculation (debugQuery=true).

Is there documentation and/or a debug command I could use to understand how the engine is coming up with the score for a result?

Answer (score 0):

When you use **debugQuery=true** in a query, you can see all debug informations and how solr calculate scores for the result documents.